# Apache ActiveMQ/Artemis PeriodicRotatingFileHandler

Tags: logging, jboss, activemq-artemis

I setup an Apache ActiveMQ Artemis broker where I want to create for each day a new `artemis.log` file.

I configured in `logging.properties` the `PeriodicRotatingFileHandler`, but it isn't working correctly.

It creates a log file for the day with the date in the filename (which is correct), but it does not create a log file for the other following days. It only creates new log files with the date when I restart the broker service.

Has anyone an example how the logging.properties should look like to achieve my plan?

Comment: Can you share your `logging.properties` with the `PeriodicRotatingFileHandler`?

Comment: handler.FILE=org.jboss.logmanager.handlers.PeriodicRotatingFileHandler
  handler.FILE.level=INFO
  handler.FILE.properties=suffix,append,autoFlush,fileName
  handler.FILE.suffix=.yyyy-MM-dd
  handler.FILE.append=true
  handler.FILE.autoFlush=true
  handler.FILE.fileName=${artemis.instance}/log/artemis.log
  handler.FILE.formatter=PATTERN

Comment: I meant your entire `logging.properties` file just to ensure everything is configured appropriately. Also, please update your question with the details rather than adding them in a comment.

Comment: Also, please indicate which version of ActiveMQ Artemis you're using.

Comment: That should rotate daily, but only once a new log message is logged.

Answer (score 0):

The `PeriodicRotatingFileHandler` checks the time only on writing a new log record: [PeriodicRotatingFileHandler.java#L115](https://github.com/jboss-logging/jboss-logmanager/blob/2.1.10.Final/src/main/java/org/jboss/logmanager/handlers/PeriodicRotatingFileHandler.java#L115)

The `PeriodicRotatingFileHandler` class could be extended, ie using a timer:

```
public class AutoPeriodicRotatingFileHandler extends PeriodicRotatingFileHandler {
   private Timer timer = new Timer();
   private long period = 5 * 60 * 1000;
   private ExtLogRecord timerLogRecord = new ExtLogRecord(Level.ALL, "TIMER", AutoPeriodicRotatingFileHandler.class.getName());

   public AutoPeriodicRotatingFileHandler() {
      initialize();
   }

   //TODO Add required constructors here

   public AutoPeriodicRotatingFileHandler(final File file, final String suffix, final boolean append, final int period) throws FileNotFoundException {
      super(file, suffix, append);
      this.period = period;
      initialize();
   }

   private void initialize() {
      timer.schedule(new TimerTask() {
         @Override
         public void run() {
            timerLogRecord.setMillis(System.currentTimeMillis());
            preWrite(timerLogRecord);
         }
      }, 0, period);
   }

   @Override
   public void close() throws SecurityException {
      timer.cancel();
      super.close();
   }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the information. Could you tell me the path of the file? (Working on a SLES enviroment)

Comment: If you create the broker with the command `./bin/artemis create broker --user admin --password admin`, the default path for the log file handler will be `${artemis.instance}/log/artemis.log`

Comment: Sorry if my question wasn't that specific. I meant the path of the PeriodicRotatingFileHandler.jave File where i can extended it with a timer

Comment: You can find the `PeriodicRotatingFileHandler.java` at https://github.com/jboss-logging/jboss-logmanager/blob/2.1.10.Final/src/main/java/org/jboss/logmanager/handlers/PeriodicRotatingFileHandler.java